# How to save the changes made in datatable using jEditable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Iam new to datatables. Iam using jEditable to make the datatable editable. In the example i noticed that if the user edits a cell and press enter key the change is saved. But in my application i want user to first make all the changes and then need to press save button. Only after pressing save button the changes should be saved in the backend. How do i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Jeditable – Edit In Place Plugin For jQuery* - I think it means it will save any changes on the fly. If you want separate action for saving, don't use Jeditable.

Comment: i just checked the document and found this:                               onblur : cancel Clicking outside editable area cancels changes. Clicking submit button submits changes.                                        Is it possible to do with this

Comment: Can you provide the link to this?

Comment: It seems that you need to set onBlur to ignore, this way the changes will not be sent immediatelly to the server.

Comment: Yes as i already mentioned i did using onblur:ignore and it works perfect.